# how to remove property of object on uncheck in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, react-final-form

I am using `react-final-form` and taking help from this example
https://codesandbox.io/s/52q597j2p

in above example `giftCardMessage` property is removed from the object when user `unchecked` this field `Is this a gift?`

steps to reproduce.

- checked the `Is this a gift?` field and enter something `Message` in text field .then unchecked see property will remove.

I used the above concept and try to make same thing .but in my example I used **prefixed** .in my example if I unchecked the checkbox it didn't remove the property of object

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-declarative-form-rules-uvz6y

```
<WhenFieldChanges
              field="gift"
              becomes={false}
              set="giftCardMessage"
              to={undefined}
            />
            <FieldPrefix prefix="apps.dh">
              <div>
                <label>Is this a gift?</label>
                <PrefixedField name="gift" component="input" type="checkbox" />
              </div>

              <div>
                <label>Message</label>
                <PrefixedField
                  name="giftCardMessage"
                  component="textarea"
                  placeholder="What do you want the card to say?"
                />
              </div>
            </FieldPrefix>
```

Answer (score 1):

The message input should be automatically disabled when the box is unchecked(value of gif is either true or false), check here https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2us7.jpg 
You should  add: disabled={!values.gift}  to your message for it to respond to the value of the box

Comment: That is right, but you should change the disabled value for this example in this case: disabled={values.apps && values.apps.dh ? !values.apps.dh.gift : true}